# Fancybox2 slideshow helpers buttons

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is there any way to specify, what are the buttons should display for slideshow in helpers of fancybox 2? Actually I don't need the toggle button.

```
helpers : {
  title : { type : 'inside' },
  buttons : {}// is these takes some button names?
}
```

How can I remove the toggle button?

Thanks.

Comment: Currently not, sorry. You can edit source code or use it as a template to create your own helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the size-toggle button without editing the source file by using the tpl option to override the default html template. The original template is contained in jquery.fancybox-buttons.js. (Note the inline-css width adjustment to the ul tag to correct for the narrower total width.)

```
helpers: {
  buttons: { tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul style="width:132px"><li><a class="btnPrev" title="Previous" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnPlay" title="Start slideshow" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnNext" title="Next" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();"></a></li></ul></div>' }
}
```

Comment: Consider this answered @Tapas Bose...  Put that sweet little check mark on it !